# Division of rectangle into rectangles

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to divide a rectangle with sides 11 and 15 into rectangles with sides 3 and 5?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, You can make a 3x15 first (3 small boxes), the put them side by side with another to get a 6x15. Then make a 5x15 (5 small boxes) and stack it along side. Total of 11 small boxes.